# Sort string with numbers in Alphabetic order in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex, string, sorting

Need to sort array of addresses in Alphabetic order.

```
a = ['20 6th Ave', '33 Test St', '123 Qwerty St', 'Hello St'];
```

Expecting output:

```
20 6th Ave
Hello St
123 Qwerty St
33 Test St
```

Thanks,Taras!

Comment: why would Hello St come before 33 Test ST

Comment: I'm assuming it's because `Hello` comes before `Test`, but then that wouldn't make sense either because the expected output shows `Test` before `Querty`...

Comment: @farhan-qasim
I need to sort by 1 letter of the word. A-->H-->Q-->T in Alphabet. Like that

Comment: You do know that Q comes before T in the alphabet...?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please dont expect anyone to do your work for you.

Comment: My fault, thanx man

Comment: I'm thinking about sorting using regex by 1 letter, but i dont know how to skip numbers in the start of the str

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it with the function sort(), through regexp:

```
 const a = ['20 6th Ave', '33 Test St', '123 Qwerty St', 'Hello St'];
 const b = a.sort( (s1, s2) => /[A-Z]./.exec(s1) > /[A-Z]./.exec(s2));
console.log(b);
```

More information about sort(): https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort

Comment: exec() is exactly what i was looking for, thank you so much!